# avoid (void)drawRect when UIView is initialized

Tags: ios, uiview, initialization, drawrect

With adapting my app to iOS7 I got the following error when an custom UIView is initialized: `Assertion failed: (CGFloatIsValid(x) && CGFloatIsValid(y)),...`.

When the UIView is initialized the drawRect method is called and stops working due to missing datas handled later by another ViewController.
The UIView is initialized when the storyboard scene containing the UIView is called.

What is the right way to make sure that the drawRect method is not called right after the initializing.

My UIView `drawRect:` method with the line where the error occurs:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect{
for (NSInteger i=2; i<=101; i++) {
    height = fieldHeight * [[bellCurveArray objectAtIndex:i-1]doubleValue];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1+t*(i-1), bounds.size.height-y1-height);
    //the height is causing the trouble due to the empty bellCurveArray in the early UIView stage
}
```

Comment: Why not code the `drawRect:` method so it doesn't cause an error if there is no data?

Comment: @rmaddy, what do you mean with that. the UIView has an custom controller with a `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect` method. this method is called when the UIView is initialized.

Comment: If the initial call to `drawRect:` is causing an error because your implementation is making some assumptions, fix the code to better handle the initial situation. In other words, fix the cause of the assertion.

Comment: I still don't see my mistake. It worked great with 6.1 but not with iOS 7. The UIView instance is created in IB and I don't understand when `drawRect` is called.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't have a custom view where you implemented your own `drawRect:` method? If you did not then ignore everything I said. My comments were assuming you have a `drawRect:` method that you wrote that is causing the problem.

Comment: Oh, I do have the custom view controller with my own `drawRect:`method. Please see my edit.

Comment: OK. Then do what I said. You need to update that code so it doesn't cause any problems when run during initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems that your `drawRect:` implementation isn't dealing well with the data not yet being set. Something like this may be what you need:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect{
    if (bellCurveArray.length) {
        for (NSInteger i=2; i<=101; i++) {
            height = fieldHeight * [[bellCurveArray objectAtIndex:i-1]doubleValue];
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1+t*(i-1), bounds.size.height-y1-height);
            //the height is causing the trouble due to the empty bellCurveArray in the early UIView stage
        }
    }
}
```

One other observation - why is your loop hardcode? Why isn't the loop based on the length of the array?

Comment: I did a similar approach with checking if the array is nil. It is still interesting that the issue never occured with iOS 6.1. The length of the array is always the same and it doesn't bother when the loop is hard coded. But thank you anyway.

Comment: The length is the same now but it could change in the future. Why add another potential bug in your code? Make it dynamic now. It will be one less thing to deal with if it changes.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid calling drawRect you can set the frame to CGRectZero in your init method